# Drawing on canvas using vector graphics android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, vector-graphics

I don't know alot about graphics and drawings but I am trying to do something on canvas, and that is using vector graphics instead of bitmap to draw path on canvas with finger , I cant find any documentation or tutorials to understand how to do that, but I know that this implementation is used by some drawing apps.

According to my searching I deduced that using vector graphics will never show pixels on the edges of the path even if you zoomed.

Please suggest any thing that might help me use vector graphics and attach it to canvas to draw, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to draw with the finger :

Assuming you have a custom View that covers the drawing area ...

On onTouch handler on ACTION_DOWN create a new Path object with origin at touch point, on ACTION_MOVE you add new segments to the Path and call invalidate().

On onDraw you draw the Path on the Canvas.

Comment: yes but my question is how to use vector graphics to draw instead of bitmaps which is the usual way to do it,thanks.

Comment: how to attach vector graphics to canvas instead of bitmap?

Comment: am trying to draw with finger on canvas using vector data not bitmaps ,please do you know any way to do that?

Comment: A Path IS vector graphics